# Where to declare my arrays and which is the better way?

Tags: c

I have a situation where

```
int main()
{
   if(some_condition)
   {
      //some code
   }
   else
   {
      char *a[] = { "","",...};
      char b[size] = {};
   }

   if(some_other_condition)
   {
     // some code
   }
   else
   {
      char *a[] = { "","",...};
      char b[size1] = {};
   }
}
```

So my question is

I need array of pointers and array of integers as shown above and there are multiple such `if()else` cases in my function. So Which is the better way to achieve this? As of now I have put my arrays where needed that is in else case as shown above.

The other option of putting everything at the start of the function and using them when needed.

```
int main()
{
   char *a[some_big_size];
   char b[size_big];

   if()
   {
      //some_code
   }
   else
   {
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
         a[i] = malloc(len);
         strlcpy(a[i],"string",len);
      }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
         b[i] = val;
      }
   }
}
```

Please let me know which of the above 2 options should I go with? I have learnt that `declare variables when needed` so I want to know what you guys think.

or

Is there a different approach all together to achieve this?

Comment: Will they always be the same arrays in each `else` block? Or are they different altogether?

Comment: Use the abstractions in your program to guide you.

Do the array of `int`s in the first `else` block represent the same things as the array of `int`s in the second `else` block?

 I would put them at the top of the function if they represent the list of IDs of some kind of object. I would put them separately, and name them differently, if they represent a list of IDs in one block but the number of days left for the tasks in the second `else` block.

Comment: @RSahu I have array of pointers and array of int , the number of values they hold and the actual value everything varies.. What they represent it list of strings and list of integers .. Yes I would rename them but for this situation what do you think is better?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first code example is better. Declaring arrays of custom size will help you to trap out-of-bounds errors more easily than declaring a single one-size-fits-all array. A minor benefit is that you only allocate memory when you really need it, but your arrays have to be really big for this to matter.

Comment: Thanks!! I also felt the first one is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following conditions:

1. If the arrays in the different `else` blocks refer to the same memory:
   declare them once, as you did in the latter case.
2. If the arrays in the different `else` blocks refer to different structures in memory:
   a. declare them once if they are to be used outside their respective `else` blocks.
   b. declare them differently in each `else` block if their scope is limited to that block!

Comment: Yeah, but is `a` and `b` in the first `else` and the `a` and `b` in the second `else` point to the same memory?

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally allocate stack variables `alloca()` should be used:

```
char **a = (char **)alloca(sizeof(char *) * (some_condition ? size1 : size2));
```

As memory allocated on the stack, no `free()` or whatever needed.

P.S. If the actual code is mostly the same for all conditions, it's better not to have many `if`'s and `else`'s - just several `?:` operators for `alloca`.

But if it differs much depending on `some_condition` then it's better to have totally different subroutines to solve the tasks independently.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that alloca is a compiler-dependent built-in which may or may not be supported by a particular compiler.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Even if some compilers lack `alloca`, yet it is widely supported and quite useful - especially in code similar to one described by TS.